# Delete request nodejs typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, postgresql, postman

My code looks like this:

```js
app.delete("/delete/:id", urlencodedParser, (req: Request, res: Response) => {
const id: any = req.params
console.log(req.params)
pool.query(`DELETE FROM allusers WHERE userid = $1`, [id]).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
})
})
```

But when I test it whit postman and go on e.g localhost:5000/delete/1 it logs:

error: syntax error at or near "["
at Parser.parseErrorMessage (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\ucim\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:369:69)
at Parser.handlePacket (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\ucim\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:188:21)
at Parser.parse (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\ucim\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\parser.ts:103:30)
at Socket. (C:\Users\prcap\Desktop\ucim\server\node_modules\pg-protocol\src\index.ts:7:48)
at Socket.emit (events.js:375:28)
at Socket.emit (domain.js:470:12)
at addChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:290:12)
at readableAddChunk (internal/streams/readable.js:265:9)
at Socket.Readable.push (internal/streams/readable.js:204:10)
at TCP.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:188:23) {
length: 90,
severity: 'ERROR',
code: '42601',
detail: undefined,
hint: undefined,
position: '37',
internalPosition: undefined,
internalQuery: undefined,
where: undefined,
schema: undefined,
table: undefined,
column: undefined,
dataType: undefined,
constraint: undefined,
file: 'scan.l',
line: '1180',
routine: 'scanner_yyerror'
}

How can I fix this?

Comment: This is really weird. You use a normal postgres database, right, and other queries work so it's not a faulty connection or something? Make sure to update the `node-postgres` package to the latest version, if it still occurs please file a bug report including steps to reproduce, or even better the malformed packet that couldn't be parsed.

Comment: Oh wait, that's not an unparsable message, it's an actual error message from postgres. Your value that you pass to `$1` is not a valid literal. Probably you meant to use `const id = req.params.id;`, not the whole `req.params`. Log its value and ensure that it's a number.

Comment: I changed the id to req.params.id and now it's working. Thank u